# Why is it necessary to cast NULL to a type in this macro?

Tags: c, macros, struct, null, expression

I have a question about some code in Eric Roberts' [Programming Abstractions in C](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/books/ProgrammingAbstractionsInC/). He use several libraries of his own both to simplify things for readers and to teach how to write libraries. (All of the library code for the book can be found [on this site](ftp://ftp.awl.com/cseng/authors/roberts/cs1-c/standard/).)

One library, `genlib` provides a macro for generic allocation of a pointer to a `struct` type. I don't understand part of the macro. I'll copy the code below, plus an example of how it is meant to be used, then I'll explain my question in more detail.

```
/*
 * Macro: New
 * Usage: p = New(pointer-type);
 * -----------------------------
 * The New pseudofunction allocates enough space to hold an
 * object of the type to which pointer-type points and returns
 * a pointer to the newly allocated pointer.  Note that
 * "New" is different from the "new" operator used in C++;
 * the former takes a pointer type and the latter takes the
 * target type.
 */

#define New(type) ((type) GetBlock(sizeof *((type) NULL)))

/* GetBlock is a wrapper for malloc. It encasulates the 
 * common sequence of malloc, check for NULL, return or
 * error out, depending on the NULL check. I'm not going
 * to copy that code since I'm pretty sure it isn't
 * relevant to my question. It can be found here though:
 * ftp://ftp.awl.com/cseng/authors/roberts/cs1-c/standard/genlib.c
 */
```

Roberts intends for the code to be used as follows:

```
    typedef struct {
        string name;
        /* etc. */
    } *employeeT;
    employeeT emp;
    emp = New(employeeT);
```

He prefers to use a pointer to the record as the type name, rather than the record itself. So `New` provides a generic way to allocate such `struct` records.

In the macro `New`, what I don't understand is this: `sizeof *((type)) NULL)`. If I'm reading that correctly, it says "take the size of the dereferenced cast of `NULL` to whatever `struct` type `type` represents in a given call". I think I understand the dereferencing: we want to allocate enough space for the struct; the size of the pointer is *not* what we need, so we dereference to get at the size of the underlying record-type. But I don't understand the idea of casting `NULL` to a type.

My questions:

1. You can cast `NULL`? What does that even mean?
2. Why is the cast necessary? When I tried removing it, the compiler says `error: expected expression`. So, `sizeof *(type)` is not an expression? That confused me since I can do the following to get the sizes of arbitrary pointers-to-structs:

   ```
   #define struct_size(s_ptr) do { \
       printf("sizeof dereferenced pointer to struct %s: %lu\n", \
              #s_ptr, sizeof *(s_ptr)); \
   } while(0)
   ```

**Edit**: As many people point out below, the two examples aren't the same:

```
/* How genlib uses the macro. */
New(struct MyStruct*)
/* How I was using my macro. */
struct MyStruct *ptr; New(ptr)
```

For the record, this isn't homework. I'm an amateur trying to improve at C. Also, there's no problem with the code, as far as I can tell. That is, I'm not asking how I can do something different with it. I'm just trying to better understand (1) how it works and (2) why it must be written the way it is. Thanks.

Comment: Your `struct_size` macro is invalid if `s_ptr` isn't an expression. If you pass `struct MyStruct *` as `s_ptr`, the code won't compile, since `sizeof *(struct MyStruct *)` is not valid C... And no, `*(type)` isn't an expression because it wouldn't make sense - what exactly did you expect `*(type)` to evaluate to?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves I don't have a good answer for what I expected. I was confused. That's why the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the macro needs to get the size of the type pointed at by the pointer type.

As an example, suppose that you have the the pointer type `struct MyStruct*`. Without removing the star from this expression, how would you get the size of `struct MyStruct`? You couldn't write

```
sizeof(*(struct MyStruct*))
```

since that's not legal C code.

On the other hand, if you had a variable of type `struct MyStruct*`, you could do something like this:

```
struct MyStruct* uselessPointer;
sizeof(*uselessPointer);
```

Since `sizeof` doesn't actually evaluate its argument (it just determines the static size of the type of the expression), this is safe.

Of course, in a macro, you can't define a new variable. However, you could make up a random pointer to a `struct MyStruct*` by casting an existing pointer. Here, `NULL` is a good candidate - it's an existing pointer that you can legally cast to a `struct MyStruct*`. Therefore, if you were to write

```
sizeof(* ((struct MyStruct*)NULL))
```

the code would

1. Cast `NULL` to a `struct MyStruct*`, yielding a pointer of static type `struct MyStruct*`.
2. Determine the size of the object that would be formed by dereferencing the pointer. Since the pointer has type `struct MyStruct*`, it points at an object of type `struct MyStruct`, so this yields the type of `struct MyStruct`.

In other words, it's a simple way to get an object of the pointer type so that you can dereference it and obtain an object of the underlying type.

I've worked with Eric on some other macros and he is a real pro with the preprocessor. I'm not surprised that this works, and I'm not surprised that it's tricky, but it certainly is clever!

As a note - in C++, this sort of trick used to be common until the introduction of the [`declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) utility type, which is a less-hacky version of this operation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is very helpful overall. My only remaining question (as with Oli's answer) is why `*(type)` by itself can't be evaluated by `sizeof`. In my silly macro (later in the question), I do that in a call to `printf`. How are the two different?

Comment: There's no fundamental reason why this *couldn't* be evaluated inside of `sizeof`, but the language doesn't allow this. The only options for `sizeof` are `sizeof(type-name)` or `sizeof expression`, and they can't be mixed.

Comment: Is the use in my macro with `printf` *not* an expression? Maybe that's what I'm unsure of. *Why* is `*(type)` not an expression?

Comment: @Telemachus I'm not sure that your macro works. If you pass in an actual pointer, then it works fine because `*(s_ptr)` means "dereference `s_ptr`" If you pass in a typename, it doesn't compile on my system.

Comment: I pass in pointers. I can confirm mine works for that use case: https://gist.github.com/telemachus/62c72005e8d514c58014. But that is how (or one way) that Roberts uses his macro too. So I'm stuck not understanding the relevant difference.

Comment: @Telemachus In this version, you'd write something like `New(struct MyStruct*)` rather than `struct MyStruct *ptr; New(ptr)`. In other words, the argument is the name of a type, not a pointer.

Comment: @Telemachus: What would you expect to be the value of an expression like `*(type)`? Say, `type` is pointer to `T`, then `T` is a type, not a value.

Comment: Thanks templatetypedef and @mafso I wasn't clearly focusing on the difference between passing the type's name versus passing a pointer value of that type. I think I get it now.

Answer (score 4):

It's a hack.  It relies on the fact that the argument to the `sizeof` operator isn't actually evaluated.

To answer your specific questions:

1. Yes, `NULL` is just a pointer literal.  Like any other pointer, it may be cast.
2. `sizeof` operates on either a type or an expression.  `*(type)` would be neither (after macro substitution has occurred), it would be a syntax error.

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about *why* `*(type)` is neither a type nor a value? In my silly macro later in the question, I use the equivalent in a `printf` call, don't I? How is that different?

Comment: @Telemachus: Presumably because in that example, `s_ptr` is an expression, not a type?

Comment: Yup. As I said in my final comment to templatetypedef's answer, I didn't think enough about the distinction between passing the type's name and an actual pointer to the type. I accepted his answer as fuller, but thanks for yours very much. This was very helpful.